# I can't set background image inside UIButton for large image from iPad in xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uibutton

I want to set background image inside UIButton in objective C using xcode 7.2.
It is working very well on iPhone and iPod, but on iPad it is not working as my requirement.
I think that the reason is image is too large in iPad.
Here is my code.

```
    -(void) showImagePickerController {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController )picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage )image editingInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString ,id> )editingInfo {
        tempImage = image;
        [self showResult];
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

- (void) showResult {
    [button setBackgroundImage:tempImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: please show some code

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't show how you are setting the image on the button

Comment: "but on iPad it is not working as my requirement."  Whats happen? Some picture.

Comment: I have posted my code again.